# Object not being added to Mongodb collection, sometimes

Tags: jquery, mongodb, express

I have some code written by someone else, it's a jquery function that takes a dynamically rendered list, and on button click is supposed to submit an object to a mongo collection through express.

The functionality works locally, and it worked for me after I pushed to heroku. However, a colleague has been unable to get the button click to work, using google chrome or safari, the page just refreshes and the object is not added. I believe I have recreated the problem but only in MS edge.

This is the jquery function:

```
function OnAddProxyClick() {
let proxies = [];

const checkboxes = $('.proxy-input:checked');

for (const checkbox of checkboxes) {
  proxies.push({
    proxyTitle: checkbox.getAttribute('data-title'),
    proxyValue: checkbox.getAttribute('data-value'),
    proxyUnit: checkbox.getAttribute('data-unit')
  });
}
//fetch returns a promise, handle it with .then and check the response to do error handling
//otherwise if all goes well we should redirect
const url = window.location.pathname + '/proxies';
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  redirect: 'follow',
  body: JSON.stringify({ proxies: proxies })
}).then(res => {
  if (res.ok) {
    location.reload();
  } else {
    //show an error here if adding proxy doesn't work
    console.log('The proxy wasnt added')
  }
});
}
```

If I remove the location.reload and leave the page to hang, the correct object can be console.logged, but isn't added to the collection.

This is the express code:

```
router.post("/:id/proxies", async (req, res) => {
let newProxies = [];
for (const proxy of req.body.proxies) {
  newProxies.push({
    proxyTitle: proxy.proxyTitle,
    proxyValue: proxy.proxyValue,
    proxyUnit: proxy.proxyUnit,
  });
}
// Add every new proxy to the project proxies array
const query = { _id: req.params.id };
const update = { $addToSet: { proxies: { $each: newProxies } } };

const project = await Project.findById(query);

//make sure we don't add a duplicate
for (const newProxy of newProxies) {
  let shouldPush = true;
  for (const proxy of project.proxies) {
    if (
      proxy.proxyTitle == newProxy.proxyTitle &&
      proxy.proxyValue == newProxy.proxyValue &&
      proxy.proxyUnit == newProxy.proxyUnit
    ) {
      shouldPush = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (shouldPush) {
    // have tried awaiting this
    project.proxies.push(newProxy);
  }
}
await project.save();

res.end();
 }
);
```

The 'update' variable seems to be there to check mongo for whether the object exists in the collection but isn't used (I tried using it but it didn't help), and I tried using await on the project.proxies.push, and that didn't work either. The only error I can find in the Edge tools is something about an unmatched tag, but this would not explain why it works for me in chrome, but not for my colleague.

How do I make sure that the object has actually been added to the collection before the page reloads?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the express code to this, it'll be a lot more efficient.

```
router.post("/:id/proxies", async (req, res) => {
    // req.body.proxies contains the array that needs to be pushed in the proxies array 
    // addToSet makes sure that the elements are not repeated   
    await Project.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $addToSet: { proxies: req.body.proxies } });
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: That does seem much more efficient! The only issue with that is that it allows for 'duplicate' entries (mongo generates the id, so $addToSet will always designate the object as unique), but that's not a huge issue, and it does seem to be working in Edge now. Thank you very much.